# iReports page number calculation

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have an application that is generating multiple portions of a report, and then concatenates them together to generate a PDF document.  We would like to generate appropriate page numbers for each portion.  I was hoping to pass a PAGE_OFFSET parameter in to each portion and calculate the new page number by using PAGE_NUMBER + PAGE_OFFSET.  Is this possible?  So far everything I have tried generates type casting errors or invalid calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you are looking to pass this page offset to iReport?

Create a new parameter for your offset: $P{offset} of parameter class java.lang.Integer. Then, create a new variable of class java.lang.Integer. Set the variable expression to $V{PAGE_NUMBER}+$P{offset}, the calculation to nothing, the reset type to Page, and the increment type to None.

Comment: I tried that initially, but it did not work.  I am using version 3.5.1, so I'm not sure if that is why.  It complains about the '+' sign not being a valid option.  I was able to get it to work with the following expression: new java.lang.Integer($P{PAGE_OFFSET}.intValue() + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue())

Answer (score 0):

try to following step

1.) create a new variable `mypagenumber;` type integer, reset type Group, increment type page, calculation type count; variable expression `$V{mypagenumber}`, inital value new Integer(0).

2.) put on your report a textfield type string, evaluation time page, Textfield expression `String.valueOf($V{mypagenumber})` to give the actual page within the group or evaluation time group and select your group to give the pages within the group.

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for "Page 1 of 3". See the value of **'evaluationTime'**
You have to write some like that:

```
<textField evaluationTime="Page">
    <reportElement x="328" y="0" width="154" height="20"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font fontName="Arial" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Page"+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField evaluationTime="Report">
    <reportElement x="485" y="0" width="63" height="20"/>
    <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font fontName="Arial" size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Answer (score 0):

The corrected version of Cristina's code for me (i use iReport 3.7.2) is:

```
<pageFooter>
    <band height="20">
        <textField evaluationTime="Page">
            <reportElement x="766" y="0" width="154" height="20"/>
            <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.toString() + " of "]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="924" y="0" width="63" height="20"/>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="SansSerif" size="9"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.toString()]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</pageFooter>
```